# How can I fix this image memory leak?

Tags: windows-phone-7

**Update**
Manually running garbage collection clears the memory so this wasn't really a "leak" per se

I have a image viewer page that I'm passing a web URL of various .jpg images.  When I run this with the Windows Phone Performance Analysis tool, my memory used starts starircasing up every time I load a new image (12 images gets me to 50MB).  I tried to clear the image cache using the method shown here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx but it doesn't seem to work.

Image viewer:

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" Height="275" Margin="0,0,0,12"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string imageurl;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("imageurl", out imageurl))
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = ThumbnailImage.Source as BitmapImage;

        if ( bitmapImage != null)
            bitmapImage.UriSource = null;

        ThumbnailImage.Source = null;
        ThumbnailImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageurl));
     }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a memory leak? Try calling GC.Collect() then GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() at the end of your OnNavigatedTo, and see if the memory consumption keeps on increasing.

Comment: Hmm interesting GC calls clear the memory.  I guess my question should be: Why doesn't the system automatically call garbage collection when it goes over 90MB?

Answer (score 2):

The system calls the GC when it thinks it needs to. On the desktop version of .NET, there's two main conditions:

- When the number of generation 0 objects (those created since the last garbage collection) gets over a predefined number
- When the available memory becomes so low that it starts to be dangerous

I don't know what the conditions are for Windows Phone garbage collector, but overall you shouldn't worry about memory unless you start getting OutOfMemory exceptions.

Comment: I'm worried about the app not passing certification when it goes over the 90MB limit. Seems silly to have to call GC manually to meet their expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You keep disposing the image and reinitializing it. Just do the following:

```
string imageurl;
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("imageurl", out imageurl))
    ThumbnailImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageurl));
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything according to the memory profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by the fact that you are continuously creating new BitmapImage objects which are GDI+ based and thus partially unmanaged. It's a rather common problem that can be rectified by reusing the same BitmapImage object. However given the design of your app it might be easier to use an alternative to the build in BitmapImage class. I always use [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/releases/view/53740) whenever I need to do anything with images on WP7. The output can be directly used in controls and it is much more performant (and has expected GC characteristics)